# C Passing array of unknown size to a function in a single variable

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

In C, I have to pass an array to a function in a single variable, and without knowing what the size  the array will be before the program runs.  The on-paper solution is to have an extra element to the array where you'll store the array's size (I think this is called a "sentinel value").  Ok, but I'm having problems implementing this.

Passing array[] as a function argument doesn't seem to work.  I suppose I can send a pointer to the first element, but how do I then access the rest of the array?

Comment: What is the problem with passing array as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, an array decays to a pointer to its first element in most contexts:

> #### 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> [...] Except when it is the operand of the ***sizeof*** operator, the ***_Alignof*** operator, or the
>   unary ***&*** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type **‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’** that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
>   register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

That is useful, because array indexing `a[i]`, is defined using pointer arithmetic: `*(a+i)`.
So, you can use the same operations on the pointer as on the array.
Still, there is one downside to this consistency: You cannot pass an array by value without wrapping it in a `struct`.

Next, a `sentinel` is an invalid value of the element type used as a stop marker, like for strings the 0 and for pointers mostly `NULL`.
What you actually described was a counted array, having the length prepended at index `((size_t*)a)[-1]` or some such.

Comment: Can you please explain or suggest a link about the exceptions like sizeof? Thanks.

Comment: The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) covers the exceptions in §6.5.3.4 **The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**: _When applied to an
operand that has array type, the result [of `sizeof`] is the total number of bytes in the array.103)_ and footnote 103 says: _When applied to a parameter declared to have array or function type, the sizeof operator yields the
size of the adjusted (pointer) type (see 6.9.1)._  Similarly, it says: _When applied to an array
type, the result [of `_Alignof`] is the alignment requirement of the element type._

Answer (score 2):

The choice of the sentinel value depends on the type of data the array stores. For anything involving a pointer, use `NULL`, and `NAN` for floating points, e.g.:

```
char *strings[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz", NULL};
double doubles[] = {1.0, 2.4, 6.5, NAN};
```

Now checking where the array ends amounts to walking along the array until you find the sentinel:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // for NULL

size_t count_strings(char **strings) {
    size_t num_strings = 0;
    while ((*strings)++ != NULL) {
        num_strings++;
    }
    return num_strings;
}


#include <math.h>    // for NAN and isnan(…)

size_t count_doubles(double *doubles) {
    ...
    while (!isnan(*doubles++)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finding a sentinel is more difficult for some data types (say, `int`), but you can then choose a conventional value.

Comment: The doubles example has an extra level of indirection that it shouldn't

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks for the constructive feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You iterate over the array whose address is passed in as the first parameter, and check the range by the array length that's passed in as the second parameter.

```
// Or, void f(int *a, int size) as the array decays
// to a pointer when passed into this function
void f(int a[], int size)
{
   // It's your own responsibility to make sure you
   // don't access the out-of-range elements.
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
      printf ("%d\n", a[i]);
   }
}

// use of f()
int a[10];
// or f(&a[0], sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
f(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
```