# Is there a way to add multiple values into an array in one command prompt?

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to scanf 5 numbers into an array in one command line prompt. I know how to store a value one by one into an array, but in this case I am trying to store 5 values in a line. I know how to hard code it when the limit is clear, but I want to code it based on a user inputted limit.

for example (hard code):

```
int arr[5]; 

scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4]);

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
printf(" %d", arr[i]);
}
```

would give me the values of arr[0] arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4].

**BUT** what if the size of aaa is defined by users, or defined by a macro that allows changes? How do you not hard code it?

```
#define MAX 10

int arr[MAX];
```

or

```
printf("what is the limit? : ");
scanf("%d", &limit);

int arr[limit];
```

I tried using a for loop but it doesn't work.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX; i++){
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", &aaa[i]);      //I want user to input 5 numbers in one line, but this format doesnt work.
}
```

To conclude/clarify my question.

**I want user to input 5 numbers in one line. for example : 1 2 3 4 5 with a space in between. and I want it stored at arr[0] arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4]. Is there a way to not hard code this?**

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an unknown number of integers with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688886/pass-an-unknown-number-of-integers-with-scanf)

Comment: You have already understood how to make a loop. Why didn't you just test to put a single scanf in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[5];

  printf("Enter 5 numbers separated by space then press Enter\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf(" %d", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Execution:

```
Enter 5 numbers separated by space then press Enter
1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read inputs in the loop as below.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX; i++) {
  scanf("%d", &aaa[i]);
}
```

Comment: what if I really want to input/store 5 numbers in the array with one line? is it possible?

Comment: You should remove the semicolon after the loop statement

Comment: @FulyzeChan This works either way, be it a newline or a space between numbers.

Comment: @Spikatrix i want a space between numbers,  how do i do that?

Comment: @FulyzeChan `%d` format specifier handles white spaces.

Comment: Doing it in one line: `for(i=0;i<MAX; i++) scanf("%d", &aaa[i]);`.

Comment: `scanf` is not very convenient for interactive input. I suggest you don't bother about input  details now but focus on learning programming. Deal with input details later once you've gained some knowledge.

Comment: umm let me clarify my question. I want user to input 5 numbers in one line.
for example : 13 14 15 16 17 with a space in between. 
and i want it stored at arr[0] arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4]. 

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @FulyzeChan yes, there is a way: `for(i=0;i<MAX; i++) scanf("%d", &aaa[i]);`. The caveat is that it also accepts newlines instead of spaces as separator, but at your level of knowledge you shoudn't bother. If you bother, you need to use `fgets` and parse the string yourself.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the answer! however, when I did this `for(i=0;i<MAX; i++) scanf("%d", &aaa[i]);`, a stale code happened. and also.... this is actually a school assignment that requires to do this...

Comment: _"a stale code happened"_: what is that supposed to mean? Maybe you should ask an all new question about this. Before writing your question you might want to read this: [ask]. Anyway `for(i=0;i<MAX; i++) scanf("%d", &aaa[i]);` for reading `MAX` values into an array will be good enough.

Comment: You can code the input in a loop, but enter them on a single line. The `scanf` of each value isn't terminated by a newline but by a non-decimal character. The newline is required only to pass the input from the OS to the input buffer.

Comment: @WeatherVane so you mean even if i did `for(i=0;i<MAX; i++) {
  scanf("%d", &aaa[i]);
}`, I dont have to press <ENTER> but a space would still work?

Comment: You need at least one Enter, after all the inputs have been typed. They can be separated by a space: try it. And note that `scanf("%d", &a); scanf("%d", &b);` is functionally equivalent to `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b); `